# Excel file not saved in user's PC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I have tried to download an excel file from the server to user's PC.  I have the following codes from the internet. I have modified the codes a bit....

But when I run the code, nothing happens.  The save dialog box is not popping up.  What I really want to happen is that the excel file from the server will be saved in user's PC by popping up a save dialog box.

Please help!!!

```
public void DownloadFile(string url)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/0ca66926-6977-43d3-9c97-f84a43f6ce5d.xls");
    var file = new FileInfo(path);
    string Outgoingfile = "FileName.xlsx";
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Outgoingfile);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
    }
}
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ url: urlLink}),
    success: function(res) {

    },
    error: (function() {
        alert("Error to retrieve selected report");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a working download file code, I am sharing what we use.

We have two call process to download code. First call get the file prepared and saved on server. Second call shown below read file content and return a file object.

**Controller.cs**:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DownloadStream(string fileName, int searchId)
    {
        var tempStore = _searchService.GetTempStore(searchId);
        var bytes = tempStore.DataAsBlob;
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            _searchService.DeleteTempStore(searchId);
            return File(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
        }

        _logger.Log("Export/DownloadStream request failed", LogCategory.Error);
        return Json("Failed");
    }
```

**View.cshtml**

Following line calls DownloadStream method on server, server send a file object that gets save on user machine.

> window.location = '/Export/DownloadStream?fileName=' +
>   result+"&searchId="+searchId;

```
    function ExportData(exportType, exportFormat) {

        var searchId = document.getElementById('hfSelectedDriverId').value;
        var model = { searchId: searchId, exportType: exportType, exportFormat: exportFormat };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ExportDriverFile", "Export")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: JSON.stringify(model)
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                result = result.toString().replace(/"/gi, "");
                if (result == "" || result == "failed")
                {
                    alert("File download failed. Please try again!");
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location = '/Export/DownloadStream?fileName=' + result+"&searchId="+searchId;
                }
            })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
            //alert(status);
        });
    }
```